# How to delete all single-line PHP comment lines through Regex in any editor

Tags: php, regex, replace, comments, geany

I have a PHP file open in editor like [Geany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geany)/[Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) which has both type of comments single-line and block-comments.

Now as block-comments are useful for documentation, I only want to remove single-line comments starting with `//~` or `#`. Other comments starting with `//` should remain if they are not starting line from `//`.

How can I do that with a regular expression? I tried this one below, but I get stuck up in escaping slash and also including `#`.

```
^[#][\/]{2}[~].*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the regex `^[#][\/]{2}[~].*` is that it matches a line starting with `#//~`.

The regex is the same as

```
^#\/\/~.*
```

---

Use the regex

```
^\s*(\/\/|#).*
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/ok18WM/1)

**Description:**

The single-line comments can start at the beginning of the line or after a few spaces (indentation).

1. `^`: Start of the line
2. `\s*`: Any number of spaces
3. `(\/\/|#)`: Match `//` or `#` characters. `|` is OR in regex.
4. `.*`: Match any characters(except newline) any number of times

Note that [PHP comments](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php) does not contain tilde `~` after `//`. Even if `~` is present after `//`, as the above regex checks for `//` and doesn't care for the characters after it, the comment with `//~` will also be matched.

Comment: What makes you think that comments don't contain `~`?

Comment: @u_mulder I see it in [official doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php) and didn't found that syntax.

Comment: In Geany when comment short-cut(Ctrl + E) is applied the comments applied contain `//~`

Comment: Comments should start with `//`. But after that I can write any symbols.

Comment: @u_mulder Right. But `~` is not mandatory, I've updated the answer. Also, previous regex [`^\s*(\/\/|#).*`](https://regex101.com/r/ok18WM/4) will match that type of comments too since it starts with `//`.

Comment: @Tushar thanks, your answer does what I need exactly and with good description too. And thanks to all who commented here too. Please don't remove `~` update from your answer.

Comment: @VickyDev I've updated the answer again. Note that `~?` is not necessary and it'll make the regex slow. So, the regex in answer is same as `^\s*(\/\/~?|#).*`.

Comment: [Regex RailRoad Diagram](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%5Cs*(%5C%2F%5C%2F%7C%23).*%2F) to understand flow

Comment: Thanks Tushar, one more thing, maybe not related to question, but how can I remove the blank lines(newline character to be removed too with above regex, when there are multiple single-line comments one after another) left by the above regex so that their traces is also removed completely ?

Comment: @Tushar pls take a look into my Angularjs question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39832694/error-rootscopeinfdig-10-digest-iterations-reached-happens-in-filter